# Rendering the navigation list from an array based on different label on toggle mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a header component where I need to render three buttons, so every three buttons have three props. One is the class name, click handler and text.

So out of three buttons, two buttons act as a toggle button, so based on the click the text should change.

See the below code:

```
class App extends Component(){
  state = {
    navigationList: [{
      text: 'Signout',
      onClickHandler: this.signoutHandler,
      customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
    }, {
      text: this.state.isStudents ? 'Students' : 'Teachers',
      onClickHandler: this.viewMode,
      customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
    }, {
      text: this.state.activeWay ? 'Active On' : 'Active Hidden',
      onClickHandler: this.activeWay,
      customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
    }]
  }

  signoutHandler = () => {
    // some functionality
  }

  viewMode = () => {
    this.setState({
      isStudents: !this.state.isStudents
    })
  }

  activeWay = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeWay: !this.state.activeWay
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Header navigationList={this.state.navigationList}/>
    )
  }

}

const Header = ({navigationList}) => {
  return (
    <>
    {navigationList && navigationList.map(({text, onClickHandler, customClassName}) => {
      return(
        <button
          onClick={onClickHandler}
          className={customClassName}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      )
    })}
    </>
  )
}
```

The other way is I can pass all the props one by one and instead of an array I can write three button elements render it, but I am thinking to have an array and render using a map.

So which method is better, the problem that I am facing is if use the array. map render
the approach I need to set the initial value as a variable outside and how can I set the state.

And I am getting the onClick method is undefined, is it because the function is not attached to the state navigation list array.

### Update

I declared the functions above the state so it was able to call the function.

So in JS, before the state is declared in the memory the functions should be hoisted isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super();
    this.state = {
            isStudents:false,
            activeWay:false,
    }

  }

    createList(){
        return  [{
                text: 'Signout',
                onClickHandler: this.signoutHandler.bind(this),
                customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
            }, {
                text: this.state.isStudents ? 'Students' : 'Teachers',
                onClickHandler: this.viewMode.bind(this),
                customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
            }, {
                text: this.state.activeWay ? 'Active On' : 'Active Hidden',
                onClickHandler: this.activeWay.bind(this),
                customClassName: 'buttonStyle'
            }];
    }

  signoutHandler(){
  }

  viewMode(){
    this.setState({
      isStudents: !this.state.isStudents
    })
  }

  activeWay(){
    this.setState({
      activeWay: !this.state.activeWay
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
            <div>
                <div>ddd</div>
                <Header navigationList={this.createList()} />
            </div>
    )
  }

}

const Header = ({navigationList}) => {
console.log(navigationList);
  return (
    <div>
    {navigationList && navigationList.map(({text, onClickHandler, customClassName}) => {
      return(
        <button
          onClick={onClickHandler}
          className={customClassName}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      )
    })}
    </div>
  )
} 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/luk17/en9h1bpr/

Comment: invoking a function at every time is expensive or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will try to explain, If you see you are using **function expressions** in your class and as far as hoisting is concerned in JavaScript, functions expressions are not hoisted in JS only **function declarations are hoisted**, function expressions are treated as variables in JS.

Now for your case you don't have to shift your functions above the state, you can simply use constructor for initializing state as

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  isStudents: false,
  activeWay: false,
  navigationList: [
    {
      text: "Signout",
      onClickHandler: this.signoutHandler,
      customClassName: "buttonStyle"
    },
    {
      text: "Teachers",
      onClickHandler: this.viewMode,
      customClassName: "buttonStyle"
    },
    {
      text: "Active Hidden",
      onClickHandler: this.activeWay,
      customClassName: "buttonStyle"
    }
  ]
};
```

}

Now you will have your handlers available as it is

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-chaplygin-grbjc) with some modification just to show

**EDIT:**

You can have default text for buttons and change it when clicking,

Sandbox updated

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay Cool :) , In codesandbox the text is not changing ? and missing of the state ternary check

Comment: yes because in your posted code you didn't have isStudents  and activeWay  in initial state, sandbox is just to show that handlers will be called

Comment: if the answer helped, please consider accepting and up voting, cheers :)

Comment: is there any way to achieve the toggle of text

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  yes, I have updated sandbox please take a look

Comment: here its updating on the array index as @ raq mentioned below answer its not based on the array index every time its creating the list on the function, but my doubt is which method is better in this case ?

Comment: I don't think you should create a new list on every render,

Comment: but here if the navigation list grows and i need to access through the index isn't, thats where i am little confused ?

Comment: can't we stop rendering the same function if the data is not changed like we check the current data and prev data in shouldComponentUpdate ?

Comment: you can also pass the index to your function, i have updated sandbox take a look

Comment: yes you can do that in shouldComponentUpdate if you are sure that render is not required for an update